# jquery functions execute but log an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I execute the following function:

```
<span onclick="ldmr()">load more</span>     
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ldmr() 
  {  
    alert("hhhhhh");  
  }
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
at Function.ga.error (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at ga.tokenize (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at ga.select (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Function.ga [as find] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.find (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at new r.fn.init (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at r (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at i (bootstrap.min.js:6)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

Could you please explain me what is the reason of this error? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information? The code you post is not the cause of that error.

Comment: Hello! This error seems to be not related with your code.

Comment: the error you got is related to some other code,not with the current code what you shown.

Comment: Make sure you have the updated and not modified version of jquery file...
you can download it here: [link](https://jquery.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap js lib i was using is depricated
i just used a new version and the error gone

Thanks